# Visual Studio 2013 cannot login

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Cannot sign in to Visual Studio using Visual Studio 2013 (Professional edition).
Anyone knows what is the problem ?
[image: Error page]

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem as well. I think it is due to Microsoft discontinuing support for TLS 1.0. Visual Studio 2013 natively calls that protocol to sign-in. You have to force the .Net Framework VS 2013 was built upon to use a more modern protocol, i.e. TLS 1.2

For me, VS 2013 Update 5 appears to be built against v4.0.30319. I forced the 32 bit framework to use strong crypto.

PowerShell script that will add the key:

```
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
```

You can find more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client

Comment: This also resolves TFS connection issue "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue following theses steps:

1. Restar the windows;
2. Connected my account in the microsoft site:
   https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/me?mkt=en-US
3. Opened vs2013 with administrator permission
4. I did login in File > Account settings Sign in
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQhgW.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).