# Visual Studio 2013 Community stop Login – the online service is not available

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, tls1.2, tls1.0

I have a Visual Studio 2013 Community stop working; i. e. there is no login to my MS account with a message like that:

[image]

I tried the solution from the link below to update registry values to enforce TLS 1.2 to be used by .NET 4.x.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement

But there is nothing changed!

Wireshark capture of login process says that with registry settings from the link above I’m using TLS 1.0 and not TLS 1.2 as the MS solution recommends:

[image]

I also tried to repair my VS 2013 installation, but all stays as is.
What else I must to do to remove that problem?

OS: Windows 7 with critical updates installed!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2013 cannot login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71476514/visual-studio-2013-cannot-login)

Comment: I did that, but solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Have you done all the steps in the linked docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client

Comment: I only set the registry values like SystemDefaultTlsVersions, SchUseStrongCrypto and so on in all branches show in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement. I don’t update WinHTTP.

Comment: WinHTTP updated, registry setting «DefaultSecureProtocols» checked, but nothing changed – Wireshark continue saying that TLS 1.0 is in use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem yesterday, and I have tried to figure out the solution.

With [KB3140245](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client) installed on Windows 7, I start capturing TLS session with Wireshark(WireShark runs from another Win81 PC on the same LAN segment).

If I have the following registry items:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

VS2013 uses TLS version 1.2, and the login process works fine.

[image: Wireshark TLS version 1.2]

But if I add extra **SystemDefaultTlsVersions=1** regitem, as [some post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72084149/151453)/[MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement) says, VS2013 will use TLS verion 1.0, and the login process fails.

[image: Wireshark TLS version 1.0]

BTW, there is no need to add extra `TLS 1.0` regkey under [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols]

My registry of above regnode is like this, which is OK:

[image]

UI feedback for TLS session success is, a mini webpage pops out, asking me for my Microsoft account name. Like below:

[image: VS2013 launcher asking for Microsoft account login]

May this help you.